# html make page a set resolutions

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi guys just wondering got some code in html,css and javascript. However i was wondering how to make that page show up in a resolutions i choose.

```
    <div class = "Web">
        <img src="../images/Web.png" alt="Web">
    </div>
```

So for example if the person is viewing it on a screen resolution of 19200 x 1200 i would want that guy to see it in 1024 x 768 then obv he can zoom in and zoom out by himself if he chooses.

The code i gave was just an example. Thanks for the help

Comment: Google responsive web design. That's about the only answer possible with the question at hand.

Comment: 19200? x 1200! What device is that? The Matrix!

Comment: The way the web is currently, there is no good way to serve two different resolutions of an image based on device. There are people who have proposed a picture tag for this. http://html5doctor.com/html5-adaptive-images-end-of-round-one/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you want it to show up in another res? Doesn't make sense to me.

If it was me I'd use media quires to define the viewing experience and use @2x for iDevices.

Or use responsive web design

http://www.getskeleton.com/ this is what i use.

Comment: Its just because iam making a simple animation and there are some stuff which i need to keep of the screen for a bit.

Comment: In that case you would need to program it in to your animation. You can't keep something off screen by changing res up and down im afraid.

Comment: ah ok. Thanks that has helped a lot